# WHERE condition adding a max value from a group by to a date

Tags: mysql

I am have 2 column related to events:

```
id    start_date           duration
45    2020-01-10 01:52:10  50
45    2020-01-10 01:52:10  60
```

I want to calculate the max end date of these events aand that this max end date is more than 2 minutes in the past.
In the example above it would be 01:52:10 + 60s, ie 2020-01-10 01:53:10

start_date is of type timestamp
duration is a float

So the first thing I do is to group by event id

Here is my try:

```
select id , DATE_ADD(started_at, interval duration second) 
from events e 
where date_add(started_at, interval max(duration) second) <= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 2 MINUTE)
group by id
```

However I get the following error:

> SQL Error [1111] [HY000]: Invalid use of group function

Any idea how I could rewrite this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for aggregaated result you need having

```
select id , DATE_ADD(started_at, interval duration second) 
from events e 
group by id , started_at
having date_add(started_at, interval max(duration) second) <= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 2 MINUTE)
```

where clause work on the original row and don't know the aggregated result  ..

instead having clause work on the selected  result

Comment: just one comment, you need started_at in the group by to be able to use it in the having, otherwise it returns that it doesn't know the column

Comment: @VincentTeyssier  correct  ..  answer updated .